# jQuery get page with use of #/page

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

Hello I have a question recently I seen more and more sites using #/pagename instead of going to /pagename which is useful because it does not reload the page.

How can I do the same thing with jQuery? http://mysite.com/id#/1 <-- would load user with id 1 if you would change that 1 to say 4564 http://mysite.com/id#/4564 the page would load user data fro 4564 with out refreshing the page it self.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you gives us examples of these sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually seeing two things:

1. The request for content is be done asynchronously (AJAX). To accomplish this look at jQuery.Ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
2. There is also a 'hash trick' to enable back button support. Typically, a standard Ajax call does not play well with the back button. For this look into the BBQ jQuery library. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

YOU are looking for the [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).  I've had great success with it, and there are triggers for when the hash changes so you can do whatever you want: load content with AJAX, or load a different slide, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at [sammy](http://sammyjs.org/).

It's a very light javascript framework intended to implement a thin-server model like this where the rendering occurs on the client's computer in javascript instead of served pages from a remote server.  This is what allows many sites to avoid doing full reloads of a page every time a user performs an action.